# How to install any theme using only comand-line?

Tags: command-line, themes

i just want to know how to install a theme using only terminal, because when i will buy new computer, i want to run the script and my setup will be fancy.

Comment: What kind of theme are you talking about, i. e. what is it supposed to theme and how is it bundled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First download a theme, of course, use `wget` followed by the URL of the theme you want to download and extract it, most are `.tar.gz` so

```
tar -xvzf path/to/theme.tar.gz
```

Then move the extracted folder,

```
sudo mv path/to/theme/folder /usr/share/themes
```

Then change the theme

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "Name of theme folder here"
```

Where "Name of theme folder here" is the name of the folder you just moved and that is it, for a bash script using only commands

```
#!/bin/bash
wget DOWNLOAD URL OF THEME HERE
tar -xvzf path/to/theme.tar.gz
sudo mv path/to/theme/folder /usr/share/themes
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "Name of theme folder here"
```

That is all.